# Android Creating Buttons With Loop But One Button Gets All The Ids

Tags: android, button

I'm creating a lot of buttons through a `for loop`, here is the code:

```
        LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
        Button btn;
        for (int i=1; i<g.length+1; i++) {
            //set the properties for button
            btn = new Button(this);
            float dp = 328f;
            Resources r = getResources();
            float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                    dp,
                    r.getDisplayMetrics()
            );
            int a = Math.round(px);
            dp = 113f;
            px = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                    dp,
                    r.getDisplayMetrics()
            );
            int b = Math.round(px);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(a, b);
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            params.topMargin = 25;
            btn.setLayoutParams(params);
            btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_style1);
            btn.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.rubik_black));
            btn.setOnClickListener(this::ButtonPress);
            btn.setText(g[i-1]);
            btn.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.main1));
            btn.setTextSize(35);
            btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Resources re = getResources();
            id = re.getIdentifier("gi_button"+String.valueOf(i), "id", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
            btn.setId(id);
            //add button to the layout
            linearLayout.addView(btn);
            Log.d("LOOKATME", String.valueOf(i)+"Done");
        }
```

All the buttons are just fine but the problem is that if I try to use one of the buttons id it's always take me to the first button.
Example:

```
Resources re = getResources();
id = re.getIdentifier("gi_button100", "id", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
button = findViewById(id);
Log.d("Hello", button.getText.toString())
```

The Output is just the text of the first button and it happens with every id I put there.
How to fix it?

Comment: any reason why you're creating your own buttons like this in the first place ?

Comment: because it's 163 buttons...

Comment: doesn't answer my question :) i'm asking why create 163 buttons yourself ? why not use something dynamic like a recyclerview, i highly doubt all 163 will even be visible at once

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: why are you not using a recyclerview ? or some sort of view with an adapter which generates this for you

Answer (score 0):

Well, `getResources().getIdentifier` is used to get existing ids,
you should use `View.generateViewId()` instead to dynamically generate ids for each `View`s you created.

But still, it's better to use `RecyclerView` to present repeat `View`s since it has better performance.